# How to return data from method in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm learning Vue.js, and I have trouble finding anything related to this topic. I fetch the data from the API, which shows in `console.log` correctly, but I can't seem to return it to the template view. I am not trying to send this data to another component; I want to display it. How do you make this happen? In React, I would `map` the result and return the HTML. How do you do this in Vue.js? Also, I am doing this in Laravel 8.

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ data }}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    let api = location.search.replace("?", "/");
    api = api.replace("=", "");

    export default {
        name: "Play",
        data: function () {
            return {
                data: data
            };
        },
        created() {
            this.getQuestions();
        },
        methods: {
            getQuestions() {
                let data = [];
                fetch(api)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(response => {
                        return (data = response.results);
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a `data` property on a Vue component, you must use the `this` accessor:

```js
this.data = response.results
```

Comment: I have tried that and this is the error    Property or method "data" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Comment: That is likely because of the `data: data` part; you're assigning `data` to the value of a global `data` variable that doesn't exist. Try initializing it to `data: []`.

Answer (score 1):

What is data here?

```
data: function() {
        return {
            data: *data*
        };
    },
```

this data hasn't been declared anywhere, you need to set it to a default value, maybe a null like this,

```
data: function() {
        return {
            data: null
        };
    },
```

then try setting it in the method like this

```
this.data = response.data
```

and then you can access it in the template like the way you have done already.

Also, it is advised to use Vue's $set method to keep the reactivity flow - so you can use

```
this.$set(this, 'data', response.data);
```

to set the data.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 data: function() {
        return {
            data: data
        };
to 
 data: function() {
        return {
            data: null
        };
```

change `creataed()` to `mounted()`

add

```
this.data = response.results;
```

in your getQuestions() in place of your `return(data = response.results);`
I think you can also kill the
`.then(response => response.json())`

in your vue template you can do

```
<div>
<template v-if="data"> {{data.somefield}}<template>
</div>
```

The idea is you set data to null, when the component is mounted you "fetch" data and save it to the data property.
Vue sees that the data is no longer null and shows you data.somefield